# queue animation after last in .each function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, queue

I'm running through a list of animations like so:

```
function katz_logo() {
    $('#logo')
    .delay(500)
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000)
    .queue(katz_subsites);
}

function katz_subsites() {
    var subsites = $('#subsites li'),
        subsitesLength = subsites.length;

    subsites.each(function(i) {
        $(this)
        .delay(i * 300)
        .animate({top:0, opacity: 1 }, 800);

        if (i === subsitesLength - 1) {
            alert('hi');
        }

    });
}

function katz_video() {
    if (!Modernizr.touch) {
        $('#home_video').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    }
}

katz_logo();
```

Each animation is defined as a function and then ultimately called with `katz_logo()` to start the magic. In the `katz_subsites()` function, I am looping through each `li` available and then what I'm trying to do is queue the `katz_video()` function after the last element is reached, but even my experiment with an alert is not working as expected.

So - the portion I'm having trouble with is how to grab that last value (which I swear I've been following the other answers on here for) and then how to then queue something after that is reached.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## Update

Progress on code - still stuck on targeting that last element in the `each()` statement and then queueing the next animation:

```
function katz_logo() {
    $('#logo')
    .delay(500)
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, katz_subsites);
}

function katz_subsites() {
    var subsites = $('#subsites li'),
        subsitesLength = subsites.length;

    subsites.each(function(i) {
        $(this)
        .delay(i * 300)
        .animate({top:0, opacity: 1 }, 800);

        if (i === subsitesLength - 1) {
            i.queue(katz_video);
        }

    });
}

function katz_video() {
    if (!Modernizr.touch) {
        $('#home_video').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    }
}

katz_logo();
```

Working code:

```
function katz_logo() {
    $('#logo')
    .delay(500)
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, katz_subsites);
}

function katz_subsites() {
    var subsites = $('#subsites li'),
        subsitesLength = subsites.length;

    subsites.each(function(i) {
        $(this)
        .delay(i * 300)
        .animate({top:0, opacity: 1 }, 800, (i===subsitesLength-1 ? katz_video : (function(){})) );
    });
}

function katz_video() {
    if (!Modernizr.touch) {
        $('#home_video').delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    }
}

katz_logo();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are miss-using the `queue` function, rather what you are looking for is to add a callback which the animate function executes on completion.

```
$('#logo')
  .delay(500)
  .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, katz_subsites);
```

EDIT in response to comment - again, same principle.
Looking at your code, something along the lines of:

```
subsites.each(function(i) {
  $(this)
    .delay(i * 300)
    .animate({top:0, opacity: 1 }, 800, 
      (i===subsitesLength-1 ? katz_video : (function(){})) );
});
```

Comment: Ah very nice, makes the `queue` un-needed for that portion. Appreciate the heads up on that. The only portion I'm missing then would be targeting that last element in the `each()` function. I think I could just apply `i.queue(katz_video)` in that regard (once I target it correctly), but any help on that would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: @Zach I'm not 100% on what your script does but I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hey @Emissary - yup, much cleaner - what's odd is that if I even change both cases of that check to an `alert('hi')` I'm getting absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Zach It's looking for a reference to a function only IE `alert` - if you type `alert('hi')` the interpreter executes the function there an then and the return value (in this case `null`) is assigned as the callback.

Comment: If you aren't getting any alert at all then js/jQuery hasn't run that part of the code at all and it's possibly a typo somewhere but it's difficult to see without having some live code I can play around with.

Comment: Now working (I'll post the updated code), you had it right - I think I can chalk this one up to caching. Sorry about that - appreciate your help!